# Should I use index on ENUM filed in MySQL database for faster SELECTs?

Tags: mysql, database, enums

I have a large table with one `ENUM` filed which holds 5 different values ... I do a lot of `SELECT` on this table with `WHERE` on this `ENUM` filed, but no `SORT` on this field though. Should I use index on this field or not?

Comment: No better way to tell for sure than running some tests, I'd say.

Comment: Yeah probably, thought one knows already ;)